# Tikz - Alignment of X and Y coordinates from two different nodes only works one way - not the other

Tags: tikz-pgf

What I mean by that, this works:

```
\draw ([yshift=0.125cm]x\i.south |- ppre.west) -- ([shift={(0.125,0)}]x\i.south |- ppre.west) -- (ppre.west);
```

This doesn't:

```
\draw (y\i.west) -- (ppre2.east |- [yshift=-0.125cm]y\i.west) -- (ppre2.east);
```

Failing with `Package pgf: No shape named '[yshift=-0 is' known`

I am not able to get this into my brain: Why would shifting a node (which X' coordinate is taken) work but the same thing for the Y coordinate doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, that's right. You need `([yshift=-0.125cm]y\i.west -| ppre2.east)`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thank you..but why?

Comment: If you look at `tikz.code.tex` you will find in line 5226: `\def\tikz@scan@@absolute#1({%
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar[% uhoh... options!
  {\def\tikz@scan@point@recall{#1}\tikz@scan@options}%
  {\tikz@@@scan@@absolute#1(}%
}%` where the `uhoh` may suggest that the author was not too keen on allowing even more options after a `-|` or `|-` ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my way of explaining this.

When you use syntax like `([yshift=0.125cm]x\i.south |- ppre.west)`, `[yshift=0.125cm]` doesn't apply to `(x\i.south)`, it applies to `(x\i.south |- ppre.west)`. The following example illustrates this fact:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=0.3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny, every circle/.style={radius=0.5pt}]
  \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (b) at (1,1);
  \draw[red] (a) -- ([xshift=1cm] a -| b);
  \fill (0,0) circle node[below] {$(0,0)$};
  \fill (1,0) circle node[below] {$(1,0)$};
  \fill (2,0) circle node[below] {$(2,0)$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If `[xshift=1cm]` were applied to `(a)`, this would first give (with the default units) (1,0) for `([xshift=1cm] a)`, then again (1,0) for `([xshift=1cm] a -| b)`. However, the red segment goes from (0,0) to (2,0), not (0,0) to (1,0). (2,0) is obtained because `(a -| b)` is (1,0), which becomes (2,0) after `[xshift=1cm]` has been applied (with the default units).

So, the fact that `([foobar] a -| b)` applies options `foobar` to `(a -| b)`, not to `(a)`, suggests that such options concern the *whole* of a coordinates expression. It seems reasonable, in these conditions, to only allow them at the beginning of such expressions, i.e.: right after the opening parenthesis.